# Escrever uma linha em arquivo texto sem usar instrução de repetição, é possível?

Tags: c#, arquivo

Preciso escrever um arquivo texto a partir de um DataSet em C#, sendo assim ficara algo como:

```
string[] lines = {"First line", "Second line", "Third Line"}
using(StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(docPath)){
   foreach(string line in lines){
       outputFile.WriteLine(line);
   }
}
```

Até aí tudo bem, porém, eu possuo várias colunas em um DataSet e preciso colocá-las em apenas uma linha delimitando por ponto e vírgula. Teria como fazer isso sem concatenar strings?

Vi alguns códigos onde o pessoal coloca "Append()" para concatenar com o delimitador, porém acredito que tenha uma forma de escrever a linha passando apenas o DataSet e um delimitador, alguma biblioteca, qualquer coisa que faça isso de forma mais simplificada, que deixe o código mais limpo e flexível a diferentes layouts.

Se não for possível fazer isso com arquivos texto (*.txt), seria possível fazer com CSV?

Comment: è e não é, depende da definição, ou do que quer, mas precisa saber porque precisa ser assim, o que tem de errado em fazer desta forma? Isso nada tem a ver com arquivos ou seu tipo.

Comment: Precisa porque eu quero algo simples, limpo.

Comment: Já ficou claro que não precisa. Mais simples e limpo do que isso? Acho difícil. Pode perder performance?

Comment: Quanto a performance não sei, até porque não testei de outras formas sem ser com o Loop. Só que eu vejo assim cara, sou eu que estou programando, então no mínimo quem precisa saber se eu necessito ou não sou eu mesmo kkkk. A pergunta vai ficar em aberto porque eu acredito que tenha algo parecido com o que eu quero, obrigado pela sua atenção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, uma alternativa se você quer "evitar loopings" visíveis no seu código é utilizar o [string.Join(String, String[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx). Porém por de baixo dos panos ele fará mais operações do que as já existentes no seu trecho de código.

O que ele fará é um loop em seu `string[]`, adicionando uma `string` de separação entre os elementos (o que no seu caso é uma quebra de linha) e concatenar tudo em uma única `string`.

```
string[] lines = { "First line", "Second line", "Third Line" };

using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(docPath))
{
    string text = string.Join("\r\n", lines);
    outputFile.Write(text);
}
```

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda, acabei por utilizar o Loop mesmo, consegui fazer de uma forma simples ocupando apenas 4 linhas onde o arquivo é estruturado de acordo com um layout, ficou muito bom.

Comment: @L.Gustavo Seria interessante você postar a sua solução como resposta então.